# MySQL - #2014 - Commands out of sync when I call stored procedure in PHPMyAdmin

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, xampp

Good evening,

Here is my stored procedure (compiled with succeed) :

```
    DELIMITER $$
    CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE GetStringOptionList (IN p_infoTypeCode VARCHAR(15), IN p_language VARCHAR(1))

    BEGIN
      DECLARE v_infotype_code          VARCHAR(15);
      DECLARE v_infotype_description   VARCHAR(50);
      DECLARE v_stringopt_code         VARCHAR(15);
      DECLARE v_stringopt_description  VARCHAR(50);
      DECLARE v_noMoreRow              INTEGER;
      DECLARE cur_stringOptions   
                 
                 CURSOR FOR     
                 SELECT infoType.code as 'infoTypeCode', 
                        case when p_language = 'F' then infoType.frenchDescription
                             when p_language = 'E' then infoType.englishDescription 
                             else ''
                        end as 'InfoTypeDescription', 
                        stringOpt.code as 'StringOptionCode', 
                        case when p_language = 'F' then stringOpt.frenchDescription
                             when p_language = 'E' then stringOpt.englishDescription    
                             else ''
                        end as 'StringOptionDescription'
                                            FROM InfoType infoType
                                            JOIN StringOptionValue stringOptVal ON infoType.code = p_infoTypeCode AND infoType.code = stringOptVal.codeInfoType
                                            JOIN StringOption stringOpt ON stringOptVal.codeStringOption = stringOpt.code;
DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET v_noMoreRow = 0;

SET v_noMoreRow = 1;

OPEN cur_stringOptions;
LOOPROWS: LOOP

    IF v_noMoreRow = 0 THEN
        CLOSE cur_stringOptions;
        LEAVE LOOPROWS;
    END IF;

    FETCH NEXT FROM cur_stringOptions INTO v_infotype_code, v_infotype_description, v_stringopt_code, v_stringopt_description;
    SELECT v_infotype_code, v_infotype_description, v_stringopt_code, v_stringopt_description;

END LOOP;

END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

When I compile my stored procedure under MySQL through PHPMyAdmin, no problem. But when I call my stored procedure like that :

```
call GetStringOptionList('EYESCOLOR', 'F')
```

I get the following error when I try to execute the stored procedure through PHPMyAdmin on http://localhost... :

```
Missing expression (near "ON" at position 25)
#2014 - Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now
```

I've tried through the program "mysql" in console mode. When I do "call GetStringOptionList("EYESCOLOR", "F")", I get blank line with an arrow "->". I don't know what does it mean.

Why ? Do you have a solution ?

Comment: aliases short be short and ecignizable but you repeat only the table names, second it is nit correct indeted that makes is har to read, last OR RePLACe mysql doesn't like that you have3 to drop the procedure first

Comment: I deed many changes but I've always the same error !

Comment: please post a data  example so that we can debug your code properly use dbfiddle, if a command get out of sync means that it has no end. so please read [mre]